# Ocaml Lwt type confusion

Tags: ocaml, utop, ocaml-lwt

I'm confused why the Lwt print function `Lwt_io.print` has type
`string -> unit Lwt.t` 
But if I run `Lwt_io.print "a" >>= fun () -> Lwt_io.print "b";;` the result is that "ab" is printed and type unit is returned.

I would imagine that this would be a type error since Lwt_io.print returns unit Lwt.t not unit. Why is the second part of the thread called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are getting confused because `utop` is being smart.

If you look at the [utop documentation](https://opam.ocaml.org/blog/about-utop/), it is written

> when using the lwt or async libraries, UTop will automatically wait for ['a Lwt.t] or ['a Deferred.t] values and return the ['a] instead

Which is why

```
Lwt_io.print "a" >>= fun () -> Lwt_io.print "b";;
```

appears to be of type `unit`. To see the real type, try the following

```
let res = Lwt_io.print "a" >>= fun () -> Lwt_io.print "b";;
#show res;;
```

You will see that as you get what you were expecting, a `unit Lwt.t`

Update:

Just to make things clear about types, we have

```
let f = fun () -> Lwt_io.print "b"
val ( >>= ) : 'a Lwt.t -> ('a -> 'b Lwt.t) -> 'b Lwt.t
val print : string -> unit Lwt.t
val f : unit -> unit Lwt.t
```

`Lwt_io.print "a"` therefore returns a `unit Lwt.t`.
This is the first parameter of `(>>=)`, and `'a` is therefore `unit`. The second parameter of `(>>=)` is `f`. `f` takes a `unit`, which is what we needed, as `'a` is `unit`. It returns a `unit Lwt.t`, so `'b` is also `unit`. This means that the final result will be a `unit Lwt.t`.

Comment: So if it is really type ```unit Lwt.t``` why does the result of  ```Lwt_io.print "a"``` activate the next function which requires unit.

Comment: I just updated the answer to give more details about the types.

Answer (score 1):

On Utop[1], toplevel `lwt` and `async` expressions are automatically run with `Lwt_main.run` and `Thread_safe.block_on_async_exn` respectively.

To disable that, run

```ml
UTop.set_auto_run_lwt false;; (* for lwt *)
UTop.set_auto_run_async false;; (* for async *)
```

[1] https://github.com/ocaml-community/utop/blob/c898602882e032ec3c5c8315d260cfbdb2f9eeb4/src/lib/uTop.mli#L114-L133